# O(n) in -place algorithm for compressing "same letters pattern"

Tags: arrays, c, time-complexity

thats my first post here so I hope im following the rules.
I had a job interview few days ago and I got a problem which I coulnd solve (until now).
The idea is (was on C but I guess its not an isuue): given a char* of n length, you should use O(1) memory comp (in-place changes), and compress the patterns of the same char to "num+char" where num is the pattern length and char is the character of the pattern. you can assume the memory is long enough to contain the expected result. Expected time comp is O(n).

Example- [abbbccccdee] ---> [1a3b4c1d2e]

my main issue here was with the case of 1 long patterns, because "pushing forward" all letters to get the 1 before it, raising the complexity. Otherwise my idea was to work with a pointer that indicates the locations of the next compress pattern, and it works only as long as the pointer is behind the regular scanning of the array.

Thanks!

Comment: Two pointers. One for reading, one for writing.

Comment: thanks for replying, ill clarify, my issue is with the case when the writnig pointer is ahead of the reading pointer,  so that it will run over chars i havent scanned yet.

Comment: Btw, you describe [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#:~:text=Run%2Dlength%20encoding%20(RLE),that%20contains%20many%20such%20runs).

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt - Given the problem statement says we can assume the input buffer contains enough space, you better believe it.

Comment: If we add a restriction that letters may not include digits, this could be done in three passes: compress non-1 letter runs first, scan to find the final length, expand 1-letter runs starting from the end.

Comment: Or you need some other restriction like "all char codes are <128" so that you could store some extra bits in the string itself.

Comment: It is sometimes non-obvious that `char buffer[256];` is actually O(1), which is the same as O(256). Having a buffer which is enough to count ahead for quite a few steps seems like a serious help. Even better, the `int frequencies[256];` is also O(1), which allows us to precompute the output buffer size in O(n) which then sums up with O(n) to compute the output string and gives another O(n)...

Comment: @ViktorLatypov A common implementation mistake with `char buffer[256], int frequencies[256]` is that 1) `char` may be negative and code should account for negative indexes - or better: use `unsigned char`  2) Select (rare) machines have more than 256 `char`.  Frequency counts should use `size_t` to not overflow.  `frequencies[256]` is questionable value here given an input string of `"aabbbaaaabbbbbaa"`.  IAC, neither are needed here to compute the final  output buffer size in O(n).

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt you can keep O(1) memory if you say that 1 length sequences don't get "compressed". E.G. `aaaaabccc` will become `5ab3c` and `abcde` will "compress" to `abcde`. This way you at worst keep the same string length (`abbcdde`  will become `a2bc2de` which has the same length)

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I assert the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64609065/2410359) is done with O(1) memory and O(n) time per OP's requirements.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica absolutely, great answer. Oviously I didn't have the right idea

Answer (score 2):

> compressing “same letters pattern”

> my main issue here was with the case of 1 long patterns, because "pushing forward" all letters to get the 1 before it, raising the complexity

Note the length needed in the first pass to keep O(n) and expand from the end.

---

2 passes.

Compress:
Walk the *string* from beginning counting character repetition:
-- If digit encountered, error out.
-- Replace any repeat of 2 or more characters with the decimal length as text followed by the character.
-- Count `single` character cases.
Note the `length` of the compressed data.

Expand:
Let `source = &s[length] - 1`
Let `destination = &s[length + single] - 1`
Walk the array from the end reading from `source` and then writing to `destination`:
-- With special detection of the the array start:
----  Detect a character lacking a preceding digit, then write to the destination as '1' + character.
---- Otherwise copy "digits + character" to destination.  Copy these characters in reverse order so with "12z", copy 'z', '2', then '1'.

Insure algorithm handles `""` case.

Similar to [@dratenik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64607548/on-in-place-algorithm-for-compressing-same-letters-pattern#comment114237832_64607548)

Answer (score 0):

Let's put @chux amazing answer into real code! The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char *compress_num_to_str(char *out, size_t v) {
    // the standard output&reverse
    char *tmp = out;
    while (v) {
        *tmp++ = v % 10 + '0';
        v /= 10;
    }
    char *ret = tmp;
    while (tmp > out) {
        --tmp;
        char a = *tmp;
        *tmp = *out;
        *out = a;
        out++;
    }
    return ret;
}
char *compress(char *string) {
    if (*string == '\0') {
        return string;
    }

    // compress
    char *in = string;
    char *out = string;
    size_t single = 0;
    for (char c; (c = *in++) != '\0'; ) {
        // the letter is going to be written anyway
        char *const pos = in;
        // iterate over repeated letters
        while (c == *in) {
            ++in;
        }
        // if there are any repeated letters
        if (pos != in) {
            // output the count
            const size_t count = in - pos + 1;
            out = compress_num_to_str(out, count);
        } else {
            // a single char
            single++;
        }
        *out++ = c;
    }
    const size_t length = out - string;

    // expand
    in = &string[length];
    out = &string[length + single];
    *out = '\0';
    // I am not particularly happy at how this loops
    // it's unreadable, but hey - it's fast and it works.
    char c = *--in; // current character is buffered to be read
    int cont; // should _the next_ loop continue
    do {
        // this should be a letter always
        assert(!isdigit(c));
        *--out = c;
        // put the letter into destination
        if ((cont = in != string) && (c = *--in, isdigit(c))) {
            // copy up until digits
            do {
                *--out = c;
            } while ((cont = in != string) && (c = *--in, isdigit(c)));
        } else {
            // the next input is not a digit
            // add a one and repeat
            *--out = '1';
        }
    } while (cont);
    assert(in == string);
    assert(out == string);

    return string;
}
#define TEST(str)  printf("%s -> %s\n", str, compress((char[sizeof(str) * 2 - 1]){str}))
int main() {
    TEST("abbcccddddeef");
    TEST("aabcdee");
    TEST("");
    TEST("a");
    TEST("abcde");
    TEST("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab");
    TEST("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
    TEST("abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
}
```

outputs:

```
abbcccddddeef -> 1a2b3c4d2e1f
aabcdee -> 2a1b1c1d2e
 -> 
a -> 1a
abcde -> 1a1b1c1d1e
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab -> 18a1b
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb -> 18a374b
abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb -> 1a30b
```